# One to many relation on Parse.com

Tags: android, one-to-many, parse-platform

I have two classes on Parse.com : Image &  User. In User class, I am saving 3 fields Name,Mobile-number & Occupation. In Image class I'm saving images.

I have to create one-to-many relation between these two classes so that I can fetch images with the corresponding mobile-number.

I have created a relation between User class and Image class on parse.com with a column named Mobile in User class. Not able to find how can I fetch the images with that particular mobile number with one-to-many relation. Please help as I have gone thru the documentation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the code to go about. You will have to think about organizing your classes thoughtfully. I am not sure how you intend to go but as far as coding is involved, the following should help.

First get the current user.

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

Since, you have "mobile" column as the relation in the User table, get the relation first.
Like this.

```
ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = currentUser
                                    .getRelation("mobile");
```

Once you get the relation, get the query on the object who require. In your case, it is the Image Object.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = relation.getQuery("Image");
```

From here, you can customize your query. Eg:

```
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject, ParseException e) {
    if(e == null)
    //your code
    //List<ParseFile> pFileList = (ArrayList<ParseFile>) object.get("images"); //something like this just to give an idea
  }
```

});

Or if you have multiple objects, use

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (ParseObject object : list) {

                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) object.get("images_column_name");

            }
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: @Advitiya Abrol, just edited the answer. Had a mistake in there..Instead of ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Image"); it is ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = relation.getQuery("Image");

Comment: Also, @Timothy Walters answer may help you in getting some insights on how to structure your datastore.

Comment: thanx .. that was working if we have default User class. But I have now edited the table name with Data to avoid confusion. Its not working with the customised tables. Hope u get it !!

Comment: Please do not edit the question to form a different question altogether. The answer posted by me was meant for the previous question you asked. You seem to have edited it to form another, a different question and posted the same question again...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110853/many-to-many-relation This creates confusion!

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I m new to stackoverflow. Shall I revert the changes to the original question ??

Comment: Yes, that would be great! That way, the answers to this post will be coherent with the question you posted. And then the many-to-many relation question that you asked won't be marked as a duplicate question. :-)

Comment: I have made the changes. Thanxx :)

Answer (score 0):

If an `Image` class only has one `User` it is related to, simply use a reference property. You could call it `owner` or `user` or whatever. You then just set this to the current user (or any other user).

Internally Parse will store just the ID of this object with some extra information to make this as a link to another class.

When you query you can simply use the current user (or any other user) to compare against that property. Again, Parse will internally just compare ID's, you don't have to think about it.

Look at the [documentation here](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers). See where it sets the `parent` property of the `Comment` to an instance of the `Post`? That's the sort of thing you want to do.

Using the mobile number to link is a bad idea, as if you change the number on a `User` then all the `Image` classes using that number are now orphaned, unless you write extra code to handle this.