# Nest many-to-many data with Parse Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, many-to-many

So I'm getting set up with Parse using the Javascript SDK. I have two collections within my Parse database. Let's say their structure looks like this:

**Media**

```
+----------+----------------+
| objectId | place          |
+----------+----------------+
| 12345    | ab123cd<Place> |
+----------+----------------+
```

**Place**

```
+----------+----------------+
| objectId | name           |
+----------+----------------+
| 67891    | Australia      |
+----------+----------------+
```

I would like to be able to query for a `Place` and get all of the media for that place. After reading the relationships section of the Parse documentation I've constructed this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Place);

query
  .get(id)
  .then(function(model) {
    var mediaRelation = model.relation('Media');

    mediaRelation.query().find().then(function(media) {
      console.log(media);
    });
  }, err);
```

But only an empty array is logged. Am I doing the query the wrong way? Could someone please point me in the right direction or get me going?

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Does place have a relation column called 'Media" ? If it does, then the posted code should find Media objects related to the Place object with the given id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Many to many relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110853/many-to-many-relation)